# AppCompat SupportActionBar problems regarding image placement

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-appcompat, android-styles

I have a problem. I have a support action bar, in which i have set an image. The problem is that the image is slightly to the right. I think it's an compatibility problem.

Here is the screenshot of the image:[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the image in the actionBar is slightly to the right(if it is not visible, believe me it is).

The image was initially correctly centered, when i was using actionBar, but when i added appcompat to the project, getActionBar() started returning null, and the application crashed. I searched the internet and got to the getSupportActionBar() method. This time the application was not crashing, but the image is not centered correctly as before. I suspect it is a matter of theme/compatibility/overriding, or things like that.

Can anyone help me?

Here is the method in which i invoke the action bar:

```
 public void initializeActionBar() {
    getSupportActionBar();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(com.entu.bocterapp.R.layout.action_bar_center_image);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff50aaf1));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

Here is the XML for "R.layout.action_bar_center_image":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bocterAppLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bocterapp"
    android:contentDescription=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc1'
}
}
    apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.7.0/Parse-1.7.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            storeFile file('C:/bocterapp.keystore')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'
    sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
}
```

And here are the styles:

styles:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
<color name="azure">#50aaf1</color>
<color name="black">#302D2D</color>
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
```

v11/:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

v14/:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

Can someone be kind enough to help me?
Cheers!

Comment: Could you post a photo of image you are setting in actionbar? Because I want to check actual photo, code seems right so there may be a problem in image itself so please edit your question and add actual image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AppCompat 21, the action bar is represented by a Toolbar widget.

Add a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` to your Activity layout.

Then set the `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"`.
This attribute removes the margin on the left.

Then customize your toolbar with your favorite layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp" >


     //Put here your layout.

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In your activity:

```
Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
```

BTW I suggest you following the Material Guidelines.
**Android doesn't use an image centered in the Action Bar as IOS.**

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Regarding the material guidelines: it is how i received the design on the app, can't do much about it.